# The Workplace is now in the commitment phase

Tags: discussion, career

Do you have a question about your career or your workplace that isn't really about software development or being a programmer? Have you tried asking it on Programmers only to have it get closed because it's not on-topic here?

Good news! A proposal has been created on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)—Stack Exchange's site incubator—to serve as a home for general career and workplace questions for all professions:

> #### [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=TXS6wD4QBeaJS6wd42Y-3w2)
>
> Proposed Q&A site for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting.

This includes questions like:

- How should I approach my boss about a raise/promotion?
- How to deal with noisy or irritating co-workers?
- How do you define business casual?
- My coworker comes to work while high on drugs sometimes. What should I do?
- What to do when you are asked “what is your desired salary” before you even get to the interview?

So if you're interested in asking and answering questions like these and seeing that there's a home for all those general career advice questions we get here on Programmers, consider committing to this proposal. The more people commit, the faster it'll launch.

Once launched, you'll have an opportunity to participate in its private beta, where you'll work with other committers to "seed" the site and fill in the site's scope.

So what are you waiting for? Go check it out!

Comment: I'm just going to say that it's about damn time. This is a needed Stack Exchange, and I think it's going to explode with popularity. I haven't been this excited about a new Stack Exchange since Programmers. Are there any plans to seed early in the private beta with some of the really good general career questions from here, though? I know that there are a few, but I'd have to search for them.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Cross-site seeding is generally (if not totally) verboten for new beta sites after poor results from previous attempts. Every site is expected to decide for themselves what questions should be asked and what should be allowed. Programmers should serve as a warning of what happens when a site is created to be a dumping ground for another site's accumulated off-topic questions.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - there's nothing stopping you seeking out **good** questions that just happen to be off topic and closed to re-ask them.

Comment: @ChrisF That just seems really sketchy, though. Especially if they start getting upvoted and I get rep for it - they aren't my questions.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - I can't argue against that.

Comment: @ThomasOwens That happened with Programmers early on. People reasked really popular questions here that already existed on SO and eventually SO versions got migrated here as well... it's a bit messy. If you wanted to reask a question without getting rep for it though, you could flag the question and ask for your name to be removed from it, so you gain no rep.

Comment: Would not Community Wiki be ideal in this case?

Comment: @WorldEngineer no, because then the answerers get no rep either.

Comment: It changed name again?

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes: likely for the final time. SE likes to do a reevaluation of proposals in commitment around the 45% mark to make any tweaks they think are necessary to get it over the edge.

Comment: @ThomasOwens The Workplace = [Professional Matters + IT Careers & Training + Professional Careers & Advice + Career development](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/613/merge-career-proposals)

Comment: @YannisRizos Are they going to merge? I haven't seen anyone from SE actually say yes to it. They really should. I honestly haven't been this excited about a new SE site since Programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) has now entered public beta. Yay! Check out their [meta discussion site](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com) for more information about how they're handling these types of questions.