# May I use the Programmer's Meta to advertise/request support for another StackExchange Q/A?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I would like to know if it is appropriate here to request for supporting the creation of a Q/A currently at the definition phase at Area 51 ?

I am not going to name it in the question, (or that would be disguised advertising :-)), however the subject of that Q/A has a matching tag at Programmers. It is somewhat linked to programming... but not quite, as it also crosses psychology for example.

So, is it appropriate here, or should I use the chat maybe ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting on the main site or even meta to publicise a site still in definition is not ok.

Posting in chat is OK.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did not explicitly see that in the FAQ, that's why I asked (although you could say it's in "avoiding questions that have nothing to do with programmers" :-)

Comment: @Jalayn If the proposal is related (somehow) to software development, you could try a [Community Promotion Ad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/community-promotion-ads-2013) for it.

Comment: @YannisRizos Woaw Yannis, I did't know that could be possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jalayn Just to reiterate (officially) — I can appreciate your need to find a community for your proposal, but that type of solicitation would not be appropriate within our existing sites. With the number of proposals that go through Area 51, it would simply become untenable for our existing sites to be bombarded by proposal supporters looking for an audience. ChrisF made the right call, and the alternatives suggested here offer some great alternatives. Good luck!

Comment: @RobertCartaino It's crystal clear Robert, thank you.

Comment: what is area 51 ?

Comment: @tgkprog - http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: nice, area 51 should be advertised at least. and how about a nice news letter that we are auto subscribed too when we sign up as new users but can uncheck if we care too? (something just once in 2 weeks but long - 2 pages and informative for those who are interested)

Answer (score 7):

Chris gave the right answer for this particular circumstance, but I just wanted to point out that promotion of an Area 51 site on an existing site's meta is not unprecedented, and can be acceptable under certain specific conditions.

For example, [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) was [promoted here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/the-workplace-is-now-in-the-commitment-phase) without objection.  The difference was, trying to attract support for the new site wasn't the primary purpose for mentioning it here.  There was a separate *germane* reason, which was the fact that we were dealing with a lot of off topic workplace-related questions at the time.

So by all means, feel free to bring up the proposed site in suitable contexts.  It's the "hey, come vote!" posts that are disallowed.

Comment: Thanks for the input Karl. I think that for the particular case of "gamification" (there I dit it, I wrote it :-), using the mechanism of Community Ads is the right choice since there is no real question about it on Programmers - yet at least, and also no open/close/migration war like for the workplace questions.